# i cannot save a response after execute the request using axios Instance (Pokedex - PokeApi)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I trying to do a pokedex using react and pokeAPI but when i try to save the response on a constant and return it this always return undefined.
c

```
  try {
    const pokemonResponse = getPokemonByName({
      pokemonName,
    })
    console.log(pokemonResponse)
    return pokemonResponse
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Ups! We had a problem with product's fetch. Details: " + e)
  }
}
```

here a codesandbox with the project

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-haslett-ngv7z?file=/src/data/storage/PokemonStorage.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 issues in the code. See [my fork on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-pascal-3gbzp?file=/src/data/storage/PokemonStorage.ts).

1. `getPokemonByName` returned undefined (because it didn't return anything). It should return `Promise` containing response from API I assume.
   Compare it to `getAllPokemons` function in the same file that actually returns `Promise`.
   Make sure you understand the [arrow functions syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions).
2. Now you need to add `await` when calling `getPokemonByName` in `async` function. This will correctly assign result to `pokemonResponse`. [See docs on async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).